# Make MSDeploy.exe deploy a msbuild generated .zip package to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, msdeploy

We have ASP.NET MVC web app that successfully deploys to Azure via "Publish..." in VS (2017). Now how to publish a web package from our Powershell script (run locally or on TFS)?

We do:

```
MSBuild "webproject.csproj" /t:Package
```

and `webproject.cmd`, `webproject.zip` and some other files generated. In the .cmd file it calls `msdeploy.exe`. Then with the publish file from Azure, we do:

```
.\webproject.cmd /T '/M:https://example.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd' '/U:USERNAME' '/P:PASSWORD' /a:Basic
```

and it breaks with:

> Error Code: ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED
>   More Information: Creating a new application is not supported by this server environment.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED.
>   Error count: 1.

Yes, we can do it via MSBuild but that uses the version control, not our package, like described at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/automate-everything).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to modify `webproject.SetParameters.xml` file with the site name and the connection string from the publish settings file. And not to forget set `/Y` switch to actually publish. And it works great!